# ActiveMQ - cannot rollback non transaced session INVIDUAL_ACK

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Is it possible to rollback async processed message in ActiveMQ? I'm consuming next message while first one is still processing, so while I'm trying to rollback the first message on another (not activemq pool) thread, I'm getting above error. Eventually should I sednd message to DLQ manually?

Comment: Not enough info to go on here, try telling us what is happening and what the errors are

Answer (score 1):

Message error handling can work a couple ways:

1. Broker-side 'redelivery policy'. Where the client invokes a rollback n number (default is usually 6 retries) of times and the broker automatically moves the message to a Dead Letter Queue (DLQ)
2. Client-side. Application consumes the message and then produces to the DLQ.

Option #1 is good for unplanned/planned outages-- database down, etc. Where you want automatic retry. The re-delivery policy can also be configured when the client connects to the broker.

Option #2 is good for 'bad data' scenarios where you know the message will never be able to be processed. This is ideal, because you can move the message on the 1st consumption and not have to reject the message n number of times.

When you combine infinite retry with #1 and include #2 in your application flow, you can have a robust process flow of automatic retry, and move-bad-data-out-of-the-way-quickly. Best of breed =)

[ActiveMQ Redelivery policy](https://activemq.apache.org/redelivery-policy.html)